# Расположение картинок с отступом при использовании Markdown

Tags: html, изображения, layout, markdown

На странице недавних [выборов модераторов ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5) отображаются две визитки победителей:

- в широком режиме:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- в узком режиме:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть в любом случае между визитками есть отступ.

При этом в [сообщении на сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12597/176217) отступ есть только в широком режиме:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В узком визитки сливаются:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понимаю, дело в использовании разных html-тегов на низком уровне. В связи с этим возник вопрос:

Можно ли средствами Markdown сайта добиться наличия пробела между визитками (картинками в общем случае), чтобы он был как в широком, так и узком режимах отображения? То есть максимально возможно повторить поведение со страницы выборов.

Опубликовал вопрос на основном сайте, так как мне кажется, что решение может быть основано на общих принципах Markdown, а не специфичных для SE сайтов. Если я ошибаюсь, можем перенести на Мету для поиска/публикации частного решения.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что данный вопрос больше подходит для Меты.

Comment: @UModeL я об этом указал в тексте, но, кмк, будет зависеть от возможного решения. Если есть общее решение, то достойно основного сайта. Если только частное с особенностями форматирования на SO, то перекинем на Мету.

Comment: Разница в CSS `vertical-align` (значение `baseline` добавляет отступ, а `bottom` убирает) и `line-height` (влияет на размер отступа)

Comment: Думаю, что для маркдауна решения не существует, потому что его основная роль отображение простых html конструкций, тюнинг просто не запланирован, поэтому всего остального можно добиться дополнительным css.

Comment: @DaniilLoban а если какой-то микс с простейшим html, доступным здесь?

Comment: Можно поправить картинку.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавить белую/прозрачную полоску? Но там всё же линк на генерируемое изображение.

Comment: Иначе поправить стили `bottom` -> `baseline`. Это повлияет на весь сайт - надо тестировать. `baseline` выглядит предпочтительнее для картинок встроенных в строку. Могут поехать сообщения где люди ради красоты добавляли в картинку подвал. Если таких сумасшедших нет, можно попробовать предложить. Стайлинг сообщений сайта должен быть где-то изолирован.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy предложить-то можно, но, скорее всего, не оценят, или даже оценят в глубокий минус.

Answer (score -1):

как  я понимаю ваши визитки должны находится в общем блоке div. Если это так, то можно использовать transform: translate(1 или 3em[на ваш выбор]).

Comment: Как это увязать с Markdown?

Comment: хм.. могу я увидеть ваш код, именно части блока визиток , и если не трудно, html тоже

Comment: Все ссылки с использованием визиток есть в вопросе.

Comment: никак не могу найти, тогда попробуйте добавить в конец блока визитки </div> вот это - <br>

Comment: как сказали выше, если убрать у img vertical-align: bottom; , то отступ появится